# What exact "resources" are released, when calling pthread_spin_destroy()?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, locking, spinlock

I have a question regarding the phread_spin_destroy() function. In the posix standard it is defined as follows:

> The pthread_spin_destroy() function shall destroy the spin lock referenced by lock and release any resources used by the lock.

So if there are 2 functions. One function, that gets called by many threads, holds a spinock and increments for example a global variable (in the example **foo()** called).
 And another function (in the example **destroy()** called), who gets called by one thread, after the first function gets called and calls pthread_spin_destroy().
These functions could look like this for example:

```
void* foo(void* i) {
   pthread_spin_lock(&LOCK); //lock the spinlock
   sleep(2); //sleep a little
   globalvariable++; //increment
   printf("globalvariable: %d\n", globalvariable); //print for debug purpose
   pthread_spin_unlock(&LOCK); //spinlock gets unlocked
   return NULL;
}

void* destroy(void* i) {
    sleep(5); //sleep
    pthread_spin_destroy(&LOCK); //destroy the lock
    return NULL; //return
}
```

*Please note, that "LOCK" is a global declared variable from type pthread_spin_t and that LOCK gets initialised with (pthread_spin_init(&LOCK,0)) before foo() gets called.*

The output BEFORE calling destroy() is as expected: the function increments the global variable very slowly (because of the sleep(2)). 
But if i call the destroy() function, nothing changes. And this part is confusing me. 
**My question is:**
Is my understanding of pthread_spin_destroy() wrong? Is it only releasing the resource "LOCK" (I mean this one pthread_spin_t LOCK variable)? 
I would expect that the spinlock gets destroyed and the other threads can act as if there is no lock. 
Thank you in advance

Comment: What exactly would you expect to change when `destroy()` is called?

Comment: That the resource which is held by the lock, gets available for other threads.

Comment: *I would expect that the spinlock gets destroyed and the other threads can act as if there is no lock.* Just why would you expect that?  If you try to use a lock after you destroy it, [you invoke undefined behavior](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_spin_destroy.html): "The pthread_spin_destroy() function shall destroy the spin lock referenced by lock and release any resources used by the lock. The effect of subsequent use of the lock is undefined..."

Comment: Yep, the problem is your expectation. There's no reason you should expect that. You could equally well expect that the system will crash since you're trying to access something that is no longer valid. You could also expect it to work just fine because there probably aren't any resources used by the lock. None of these expectations are justified unless you have detailed knowledge about how the particular platform implements spinlocks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resources released by `pthread_spin_destroy()` are whatever resources the implementation needed to allocate to implement the spinlock as part of `pthread_spin_init()` (which, depending on the implementation, may be "none at all").

It's undefined behaviour to call `pthread_spin_lock()` again on the lock after you've called `pthread_spin_destroy()`, until another call to `pthread_spin_init()`.  It's just a deallocation function: don't call it unless you're completely done with the lock and won't need to lock it again (typically, you'd call `pthread_spin_destroy()` on a spin lock that is embedded in another data structure that you're about to free).